# Stop webpack-dev-server from focusing browser tab where site is already opened

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Here's what happens:

1. I start webpack-dev-server with `{ devServer: { open: false } }` (it's the default, but I tried making it explicit anyway; doesn't help).
2. I open `http://localhost:8080` in the browser. It shows the page alright.
3. I `Command+Tab` to some other window, hiding the browser window behind it.
4. I change something in a `.js` file watched by webpack-dev-server and save it.
5. webpack-dev-server kicks in, re-emits assets (so far so good) and...
6. The browser window with the previously-opened `localhost` tab pops up out of nowhere and takes the focus, positioning itself in front of whatever I was working on then.

So with `{ open: false }` I stop WDS from opening a **new** tab every time I change something, which is good. But how do I stop WDS from auto-focusing the tab I had already opened?

Comment: Weird.. I've no such problem on Windows10+Chrome+Webpack4.19.1, neither with `open: true`. Sounds stupid, but just in case, open your browser with your site, open devtools, enter this reload script `setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()}, 5000);` and suddenly switch back to your development IDE to be sure it's because of devserver :)

Comment: If I do that, then the page reloads in the background. The browser window doesn't steal the focus back.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? It's really annoying :-/

Answer (score 0):

For me, enabling the hot module replacement (using `webpack serve --hot`) solved that issue.